# How to build Boost as static libraries under Mountain Lion and XCODE 4.6

Tags: c++, macos, boost, xcode4.6

I'm trying to install and use Boost 1_53_0 on MAC OS X Mountain Lion and use it with the latest XCODE 4.6  I want to port a small MS VS MFC C++ app. I developed on Windows to MAC.

Specifically I need to install and build boost as static libraries.  I'm completely new to programming on the MAC.  I understand that XCODE now uses
LLVM Clang, with libc++ and not GCC.  I've used GCC some on Linux.

I started following the instructions at:
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html

but quickly ran into trouble.  Does anyone have detailed instructions for how to install and compile boost statically under Mountain Lion and XCode 4.6?

Below is the terminal input and output showing how far I got.

Thanks.

Terminal IO:

```
./bootstrap.sh --with-bjam=BJAM --with-toolset=TOOLSET  
users-Mac-mini:boost_1_53_0 user$ ./bootstrap --with-bjam=BJAM --with-toolset=TOOLSET

-bash: ./bootstrap: No such file or directory

users-Mac-mini:boost_1_53_0 user$ ./bootstrap.sh --with-bjam=BJAM --with-toolset=TOOLSET

-n Detecting Python version... 

2.7

-n Detecting Python root... 

/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7

-n Unicode/ICU support for Boost.Regex?... 

not found.

Generating Boost.Build configuration in project-config.jam...

Bootstrapping is done. To build, run:
    ./b2

To adjust configuration, edit 'project-config.jam'.

Further information:
   - Command line help:
     ./b2 --help
   - Getting started guide: 
     <had to remove link in order to post question>
   - Boost.Build documentation:
      <had to remove link in order to post question>

users-Mac-mini:boost_1_53_0 user$ ./b2 link=static threading=multi toolset=darwin cxxflags="-arch i386 -arch x86_64" macosx-version=10.6 stage

-bash: ./b2: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Not a mac expert, but two things that I'd check--first, do you need to specify "darwin" as in TOOLSET=darwin or some such, in the bootstrap, and secondly, a) does ./b2 exist (was it supposed to be built by bootstrap?) and b) if it does, does it have the executable bit set?

Comment: After running `bootstrap`, do you see `b2` file?

Comment: no b2 is nowhere to be found on the system.

Comment: Run `./bootstrap.sh` with no parameters and see whether it helps.